# Cant get a button to scroll div`s overflow with js

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

i've been struggling to get the button working, and I've tried everything I could think of before asking here. What I'm trying to do is to get the buttons on the left & right of the div with overflow, to scroll it.
I'm relatively new to web-frontend and just learning CSS & HTML.
I also really need it to remain in the css grid format, as its just a block for a website i'm trying to do. Also if possible please give answers as codepen's/snippets. I've tried allot of inserting & pasting of js already but to no result. I know that this could also be implemented with a plugin or a framework. However it is essential for me to understand why it isn`t working in order to learn :)

Here is my codepen attempt:

```js
function scrolll() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementByClassName("scnd");
  elmnt.scrollLeft += 50;
}
```

```css
body {
  min-width: 200px;
  /* solution for img overflow */
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: grid;
  margin: 5%;
}

.box {
  grid-row-gap: 0.3em;
  display: grid;
  justify-self: center;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 25%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 7fr 1fr;
}

.box div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.box .frst {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.box .frst img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.scnd {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.thumb {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.thumb img {
  max-height: 10vw;
}

#left {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

#right {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="frst">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500/?random">
      </div>
      <button id="left" onclick="scrolll()"><</button>
      <div class="scnd">
        <div class="thumb">
          <a href "#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/175/100/?random"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
          <a href "#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/175/100/?random"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
          <a href "#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/175/100/?random"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
          <a href "#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/175/100/?random"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
          <a href "#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/175/100/?random"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
          <a href "#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/175/100/?random"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
          <a href "#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/175/100/?random"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
          <a href "#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/175/100/?random"></a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <button id="right">></button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

p.s. give some time for the images to load please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the requested fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/52n8tsvb/

```
var scrolll = function() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("scnd")[0];
  elmnt.scrollLeft += 50;
}
```

The issue was that you misspelled document.getElementsByClassName, and treated the output like document.getElementByID, document.getElementsByClassName always returns an HTMLCollection, which you can treat like an array.

Comment: Thanks allot for your reply !!!!!!
I was starting to think that the problem lies in my css or html.

Comment: No problem! For future reference, the getElementX function to get a element by the tag name also returns and HTMLCollection, and uses plural elements: getElementsByTagName("tagname")

Answer (score 1):

I saw a few syntax errors in your code.. rest it works fine

function scrolll() {

var elmnt = document.`getElementsByClassName`("scnd")`[0];`

elmnt.scrollLeft += 50;
}

I tried on codepen. here is the link
https://codepen.io/shivani137/pen/GdzaxJ?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks allot for your reply !!!!!!
I can`t believe that the whole issue was in the syntax of js :(
I guess I need to pay more attention to syntax from now on